# Reading yaml config files in golang, do I always need structs?

Tags: go

I would like to read configuration constants from a yaml in Golang.

Example:
I have config.yml

```
server:
  host: "localhost"
  port: 8080
```

And a config struct

```
type Config struct {
    Server struct {
        Port string `yaml:"port"`
        Host string `yaml:"host"`
    } `yaml:"server"`
}
```

Then I could read it like this:

```
f, err := os.Open("config.yml")
if err != nil {
    processError(err)
}

var cfg Config
decoder := yaml.NewDecoder(f)
err = decoder.Decode(&cfg)
if err != nil {
    processError(err)
}
```

I'm using gopkg.in/yaml.v2

I want to parse it and then read the constants, do I need to have a struct with the configuration 
structure ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unmarshal a yaml file into an interface{}:

```
var data interface{}
yaml.Unmarshal(input,&data)
```

One thing to note is that the https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2 library unmarshals to map[interface{}]interface{}, instead of a map[string]interface{}.